# Trying to get my navbar button to work when the screen is in tab or on mobile mode

Tags: html, css

So I have my navbar and i have a button so when the screen is shrunk down to a certain size the navbar becomes the button with the three lines that should be a dropdown and it is not working. I am trying to have it act as a dropdown that I can then use the links to the other pages for to navigate this page. The button shows up when it's needed and it is a button, when hovered on or clicked it changes to grey. However clicking it does northing.

My HTML and CSS:

```css
/* navbar styling */

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: crimson;
}

.navbar .max-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .logo a span {
  color: crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 25px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
  color: crimson;
}

.navbar.sticky .menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* menu btn styling */

.menu-btn {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 23px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.scroll-up-btn {
  position: fixed;
  height: 45px;
  width: 42px;
  background: crimson;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.scroll-up-btn.show {
  bottom: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.scroll-up-btn:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Edward Wynman</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="Resume.pdf">Resume</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty easy to fix with the use of some Javascript, as you can see with this snippet, you can now make it collapse and uncollapse when clicking the button.

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbarNav");

function hideShow() {
  if (navbar.style.display == "block") {
    navbar.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    navbar.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
/* navbar styling */

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: crimson;
}

.navbar .max-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .logo a span {
  color: crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 25px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
  color: crimson;
}

.navbar.sticky .menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* menu btn styling */

.menu-btn {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 23px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.scroll-up-btn {
  position: fixed;
  height: 45px;
  width: 42px;
  background: crimson;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.scroll-up-btn.show {
  bottom: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.scroll-up-btn:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Edward Wynman</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="hideShow()">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="Resume.pdf">Resume</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where in the code would i put it. would it be after the navbarNav div. would it be <script> CODE </script>

Comment: @EdwardWynman You would put the JavaScript in `<script>CODE</script>` and usually script elements are at the bottom of the body, but they can be anywhere in the body.